# There are a bunch of crons in /etc/cron.d but crontab -l doesn't show

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I am with root on an Ubuntu 16.04.

Inside `/etc/cron.d` there are these files:

```
root@server:/etc/cron.d# ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  589 Jul 16  2014 mdadm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  670 Mar  1  2016 php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2471 Dec  2 19:44 sendmail
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   77 Jan 14 20:56 my_cron_weekly
```

As you can see there are a bunch of crons, and in particular `"my_cron_weeky`" is a script that I have added.

The issue is, if i type: `crontab -l`, i get:

```
root@server:/etc/cron.d# crontab -l
no crontab for root
```

How can I check that those scripts inside `/etc/cron.d` are read fine from cron?

Answer (score 2):

`crontab -l` only shows the contents of the user’s crontab, stored in the cron spool directory (`/var/spool/cron/crontabs` on Ubuntu). It doesn’t take files under `/etc/cron.d` (or `/etc/cron.daily` etc.) into account.

To see whether the cron scripts are being processed, you can look at the emails `cron` sends, or its logs. On Ubuntu `cron` logs using the “cron” syslog facility; the cron logs might be disabled by default, you should check your system logger’s configuration. You could also make your `my_cron_weekly` job leave traces of its execution and look for those (*e.g.* write something to a specific file...).

Comment: I know that I could log my_cron_weekly exectuion somewhere, but i am surprised that the standard crontab tool doesn't have any way to show crons from that folder

Comment: The `crontab` tool manipulates crontabs; `/etc/cron.d` and so on aren’t crontabs ;-). I know that’s rather pedantic and it would be useful to have a tool to list everything...

Comment: @StephenKitt but what are they, if not crontabs ?

Comment: @Ciprian like I said in the comment I was being pedantic. The distinction is that the spool crontabs are user crontabs (including root’s), and those are what the `crontab` command manipulates; files under `/etc/cron.d` are equivalent to the system crontab in `/etc/crontab`, don’t follow quite the same format as user crontabs, and aren’t managed by `crontab`.

Comment: thanks, @StephenKitt ! Any idea of how I can debug whether the files in `cron.d` have been sucessfully picked up? I read around here that the `cron` may only reload them every hour or so

Answer (score 1):

You can put this file there (don't forget to delete it afterwards):

```
* * * * * root touch /root/cron.d.ok
```

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/cron.d`  ===> is owned by the system and by the package management system.

`crontab -l`   ===> Consists of user cron's

Comment: so which is the equivalent of system crontab ?